# Edit CSV based on sequence of strings

Tags: shell, csv, unix, apache-spark, mapreduce

I have a csv file with a text string at the beginning of every line ,before another long XML string begins. The below is a single line, which I formatted as XML for convenience.

```
    0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5<Company xmlns="abcd">
    <Employee>
        <Id>999999</Id>
        <Name>Hulk</Name>
        <Email>hulk@smash.com</Email>
    </Employee>
    <ApplicationName/>
    <Identifier/>
    <Headquarter>
        <City>XYZ</City>
        <House>123</House>
    </Headquarter>
</Company>
```

I need to extract the starting text until the first appearance of "<" where the xml begins and modify each line like below:

```
<Record> -- adding parent xml enclosure
<Parent_id>0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5</Parent_id> -- for reference
<Company xmlns="abcd">
    <Employee>
        <P_id>0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5</P_id> -- replicating p_id under each xml tag groups
        <Id>999999</Id>
        <Name>Hulk</Name>
        <Email>hulk@smash.com</Email>
    </Employee>
    <ApplicationName/>
    <Identifier/>
    <Headquarter>
        <P_id>0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5</P_id> -- same here
        <City>XYZ</City>
        <House>123</House>
    </Headquarter>
</Company>
</Record>
```

I am assuming it would need multiple iterations to achieve this, but I am open to any ideas. Tools at disposal are shell, map reduce or any efficient way to perform this on each line of a file.

Thank you!

Comment: What does the input data actually look like? Is it actually all on one line?

Comment: Yes..its a csv. with an unique identifier at the beginning of each line followed  by XML string.

something like this:
0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5<Company xmlns="abcd"><Employee><Id>999999</Id><Name>Hulk</Name><Email>hulk@smash.com</Email></Employee><ApplicationName/><Identifier/><headquarter><city>XYZ</city><house>123</house></headquarter></Company>

Comment: Well,if it helps,  in short, I am trying to convert a csv with a well structured xml string into another outer xml ,based on string position and char sequence.

Comment: It's not really CSV though, is it? Is there a comma (or other separator) between the leading data and the first angle bracket of the XML? These questions don't relate to solving this question, but please do think about how you talk about your data. CSV is a well-defined file format, and this data doesn't appear to be CSV data.

Comment: @glennjackman Apologies. I should not have specified csv. It should be considered as a regular text file which is actually an underlying text file for a hive table.
each field is separate by "^A" and ends with $.


------------------
the hive table definition included:
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat file
0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5<Company xmlns="http://example.com/abcd"><Employee><Id>999999</Id><Name>Hulk</Name><Email>hulk@smash.com</Email></Employee><ApplicationName/><Identifier/><headquarter><city>XYZ</city><house>123</house></headquarter></Company>
```

Then:

```
IFS='<' read -r string xml < file
xml="<$xml"   # add the leading bracket that the read command removed.
{ 
    echo "<Record>"
    xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
        --subnode /_:Company/_:Employee    --type elem --name P_id --value "$string" \
        --subnode /_:Company/_:headquarter --type elem --name P_id --value "$string" \
        --subnode /                        --type elem --name Parent_id --value "$string" \
            <<<"$xml"
    echo "</Record>"
}
```

Outputs

```
<Record>
<Company xmlns="http://example.com/abcd">
  <Employee>
    <Id>999999</Id>
    <Name>Hulk</Name>
    <Email>hulk@smash.com</Email>
    <P_id>0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5</P_id>
  </Employee>
  <ApplicationName/>
  <Identifier/>
  <headquarter>
    <city>XYZ</city>
    <house>123</house>
    <P_id>0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5</P_id>
  </headquarter>
</Company>
<Parent_id>0b51b828-9416-4933-80ad-dd44ae2377b5</Parent_id>
</Record>
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn. The output looks promising. But it seems the environment I am working do not have access to xmlstartlet toolkit. any other workaround?